# How can I get from LYS airport to the city center of Lyon?

Tags: airport-transfer, transportation, lyon, lys

My flights will be arriving at LYS airport on a Thursday afternoon (around 2 o'clock and leaving on a Sunday evening (around 8 o'clock).

From the airport I want to get to the city center and specifically Foch metro station. 
For the trip back I want to start at Foch station and get to the airport.

What is the best way to do this?
In order to make the question more specific my preferred means of transportation are as follows in order of preference.

1. Metro or train (I haven't found any lines that go to the airport though)
2. Bus
3. Taxi

Comment: @DavidRicherby Google Maps _does not_ indicate any transit connections to the LYS airport at all, despite their existence.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Gosh, Google thinks you need to take a train to a town in completely the wrong direction and then get a bus to the airport from there; total journey time 2.5hrs. \*boggle\*

Comment: @DavidRicherby Oh yes, other than that one. Which is completely useless.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much the easiest way to get between Lyon and LYS is the [Rhônexpress](https://www.rhonexpress.fr/en). It runs  every 15-30 minutes from 4:30 am to midnight and costs 28,30€ return (or less in advance). The journey takes about 30 minutes.

From Gare de Lyon-Part Dieu it is a 2.1km walk to Foch metro station, or you can [take the light rail to Charpennes station and then change to the subway there](http://tcl.fr/Me-deplacer/Itineraires/Mon-trajet/(_rd)/1558208494469?ItinDepart=Gare%20de%20Lyon%20Part-Dieu%2C%20Lyon&valueItinDepart=Address%7C162086%7CGare%20de%20Lyon%20Part-Dieu%7CLyon%7C%7C%7C796308%7C2087606&valueItinDepartFavoris=Address%7CADDRESS161265%7CGare%20de%20Lyon%20Part-Dieu%7CLyon%7C%7C%7C796308%7C2087606&ItinArrivee=Foch%2C%20Lyon%206eme%20%28Arr%C3%AAt%29&valueItinArrivee=StopArea%7C2178%7CFoch%7CLyon%206eme%7C%7C%7C795021%7C2088471&valueItinArriveeFavoris=StopArea%7Ctcl5182%7CFoch%7CLyon%206eme%7C%7C%7C795021%7C2088471&lancer_recherche_trajet=Rechercher&action=add&refer=trajet&radioSens=HorPartir&DepartMinute=45&radioTiming=DepartImm&radioOption=OptionArrivRapid&radioModes=OptionPrivilTous).

Comment: +1: this answer is great. Taxi or Uber will cost you at least the double, but it’s an option too, specially if you travel with other people.